# Multiples VirtualHost for Symfony3 projects in AWS development environment

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualhost, symfony

We have a problem with access to multiple Symfony3 projects that are in different folders and  targeted to the same IP address but in different ports on EC2, for example:

project1:

- 52.1.1.1:8080/login
- /var/www/html/projects/project1/

project2:

- 52.1.1.1:8181/login
- /var/www/html/projects/project2/

Happens that when entering the ***Project 1*** (52.1.1.1:8080) it is displayed correctly, but afterward when accessing to ***Project 2*** (52.1.1.1:8181), this fails, strangely deploys the information from ***Project 1***.

In another scenario, when rebooting the apache service and entering the **Project2** (52.1.1.1:8181) all is displayed correctly, but if after entering in the **Project2**, we enter the **Project 1** (52.1.1.1:8080) the information from **Project2** is displayed, instead of that of the **Project 1**.

Ports **8080** and **8181** are open.

Apache configuration on the server is the following:

```
Listen 8181
<VirtualHost *:8181>
    DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/projects/project1/web"
    DirectoryIndex  app.php
    <Directory "/var/www/html/projects/project1/web">
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All    
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/html/projects/project1>
           Options FollowSymlinks  
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/projects/project1/web/bundles>
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine Off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    CustomLog  /var/www/html/projects/project1/var/logs/reg-access.log combined
    ErrorLog   /var/www/html/projects/project1/var/logs/reg.error.log
</VirtualHost>

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/projects/project2/web"
    DirectoryIndex  app.php
    <Directory "/var/www/html/projects/project2/web">
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All    
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/projects/project2>
           Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/projects/project2/web/bundles>
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine Off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    CustomLog  /var/www/html/projects/project2/var/logs/reg-rm.log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/www/html/projects/project2/var/logs/reg.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help or ideas about what happens?

**UPDATED**

To access the Project 1, logs the following error:

[2016-08-17 07:33:12] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Target" at /var/www/html/projects/**project2**/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/Annotation/Target.php line 31 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Target at /var/www/html/projects/**project2**/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/Annotation/Target.php:31)"} []

"Vendors" is referenced strangely to another project

Comment: What browser are you entering 52.1.1.1:8080?

Comment: Entering with Safari, chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Your issue is totally related to Browser cache I guess load 52.1.1.1:8181 and 52.1.1.1:8080 on two separate laptop or computer and see if that issue persists.

Comment: I thought the same you mention @error2007s, tried in different browsers on different computers and in two different networks and the result is the same.

Comment: Ok but this is definitely a caching issue I am not familiar with Symphony3 though

Comment: Thanks @error2007s, i'll research!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution, I had to modify the "app/autoload.php" file

**Before**

```
$ loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

**After**

```
$ loader = require __DIR__.'/../../project1/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And it all worked properly.

But I communicated with Javier Eguiluz and he suggested to try installing APC on the server, I installed it, rolled back the changes to the file "app/autoload.php" and it worked properly.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT #2 based on your comment.

```
Listen 8181
<VirtualHost *:8181>
    Servername project1.com
...

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Servername project2.com
     DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/projects/project2/web"
    DirectoryIndex  app.php
```

On a remote host edit your hosts file to include the above host names.
For example, if you are on a remote Windows host, edit the file "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" as follows:

```
52.1.1.1  project1.com
52.1.1.1  project2.com
```

Then in your browser use:

```
http://project1.com:8181
http://project2.com:8080
```

This should work. Please investigate first before downvoting. Thanks!

Comment: I added it and continues the problem! :/

Comment: This should work, but instead of using the IP address like you are using, are you able to map host names to IP addresses (for example do you have a name server)? Then instead you can map to host names. That's exactly the purpose of the `VirtualHost` directive. Don't know why the down vote? Probably from someone who is not familiar with Apache. The way you could test this is by modifying a remote hosts file. I'll edit my post and show an example.

Comment: I understand what indicas, but did not want to do it that manner because have other projects on another server running on different ports without any problem, anyway will have to do it that way unless find another solution. Thanks!